# Action_Helper in separte module does not get loaded

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-modules

I followed this great article http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets.html, but currently i can't get work my simplified example.

PROBLEM *The preDispatch does not get loaded*.

I created new module **user** (there is also controller **UserController**, i hope this wont mess up the loading).

I have added two files in **user**.

Bootstrap.php - under module user

```
class User_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {

public function initResourceLoader() {
    $loader = $this->getResourceLoader();
    $loader->addResourceType('helper', 'helpers', 'Helper');
}

protected  function _initHelpers() {
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
        new User_Helper_HandleLogin()
    );
}
```

New folder under /user/helpers and class HandleLogin.

```
class User_Helper_HandleLogin extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract {

protected $view;

public function preDispatch() {
    echo 'called';
    if (($controller = $this->getActionController()) === null) {
        return;
    }

    $this->createProfileWidget();
}

public function createProfileWidget() {
    if (!$view = $this->getView()) {
        return;
    }
    $view->user = '<h2>HELLO WORLD</h2>';
}

public function createLoginForm() {

}

public function getView() {
    if ($this->view !== null) {
        return $this->view;
    }

    $controller = $this->getActionController();
    $view = $controller->view;

    if (!$view instanceof Zend_View_Abstract) {
        return;
    }

    //$view->addScriptPath(dirname(__FILE__) .'/../views/scripts');
    $this->view = $view;
    return $view;
}
```

}

And lastly added into layout.phtml the output.

```
<?php echo $this->user ?>
```

Comment: is `init()` function of User_Helper_HandleLogin works? is User_Bootstrap works? :) maybe you forget `resources.modules[] =` in `config.ini`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is `init()` function of `User_Helper_HandleLogin` works? is `User_Bootstrap` works? :) maybe you forget `resources.modules[] =` in `config.ini`?

Comment: I added the handleLogin() but still there's problem with finding and loading the plugin. The handleLogin plugin is registered in *User* modules bootstrap so this should autoload? I cant make separate post error is Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'HandleLogin' was not found in the registry; used paths: ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_: ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/ Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/var/www/review/application/views/helpers/' in /home/risto/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php:412 Stack trace: #0

Comment: Thank you, adding the resources.modules[] line and it works now, the only explanation what i found is from akrabat.com site "resources.modules tells Zend_Application to load the modules resource which in turn looks for module bootstrap classes." that's exactly what i need.